# Can we say that php is a compiled language after adding JIT?

Tags: php

Today I read an [article about the JIT compiler](https://thephp.website/en/issue/php-8-jit/) and a fragment of text from this article:

> *Translating human-readable code to machine code can happen in three different ways: Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation, Just In Time (JIT)
> compilation or, our favorite, interpretation (or Implicit
> Compilation).*

gave me the following thoughts:

One of the popular questions about php is whether php is a compiled language or an interpreted language. If you google it now, you will get a seemingly clear answer, but is it?

[image]

A JIT compiler was added to PHP 8. Can we now say that PHP since version 8 is a compiled language? Or would "partially compiled" be a better definition?

Comment: This is just my opinion: Although it is clear what a purely interpreted or compiled language is, many languages fall somewhere in between. Perhaps the best criteria you can use is to look at what you give to someone when you share your program. Do you give them the source code, then it is interpreted, do you give them an executable, then it is compiled. From that perspective standard PHP is still solidly an interpreted language. But opinions can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the addition of Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation in PHP 8, you can say that PHP has gained some aspects of compiled languages, but it's not typically referred to as a fully compiled language.

Here's why:

1. Still Interpreted: The majority of PHP code is still interpreted, meaning that the PHP source code is executed directly by the PHP interpreter without prior compilation to machine code.
2. JIT for Optimization: The JIT compiler in PHP 8 is used for certain parts of the code to improve performance. It compiles specific sections of code into machine code at runtime, but not the entire program.
3. Dynamic Typing: PHP remains a dynamically typed language, where variable types can change at runtime. Compiled languages like C or C++ are often statically typed, where variable types are determined at compile time.

So, while PHP 8 introduces JIT compilation and provides performance benefits for certain code segments, PHP is not typically categorized as a fully compiled language like C or C++. It's more accurately described as a dynamically interpreted language with some optional JIT compilation for optimization.